# subscripted labels conversion from vb6 to vb.net

Tags: vb6-migration

i have just started to update a legacy vb6 project to vb.net (I know its late, I know) and I have many screens with labels where they all have the same name ( ie lbl_label()) and in vb6 this is subscripted because the label is not referred in the code.  how do I deal with this in vb.net do I really have to create a different label name for each one?
Not hard to call it lbl_label1 lbl_label2 etc but will be a tad tedious by the 77th form.
TIA

Comment: Show some examples and what you tried so far...

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion it is impossible. If you have many forms why not apprebndre WPF or UWP and develop a small application to insert the controls in the XAML file?

Why do you want migrate a VB6 application in an obsolete technology?